# binary tree from pre-order traversal with absent children specified

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, preorder

I have a binary tree represented by pre-order traversal, which looks like this: `{1 4 6 10 0 0 0 7 0 8 0 0 2 5 0 0 3 9 0 0 0 }`, where a 0 indicates the absence of child of an element.

How do I construct the original binary tree from this data? I've tried to solve problem with recursion, but I haven't realized how to deal with right children of nodes, as I can't calculate their position in the array unless they have a leaf as a parent (the case when leaf has two zeros after it, which indicate that it has no children).

I feel like the solution has to be pretty easy, but still don't see it.

Comment: *unless they have a leaf as a parent*. How can leaf be a parent? Don't you think this is contradictory to what leaf is?

Comment: it can't be, but I mean the case when leaf has two zeros after it, which indicate that it has no children.

Comment: When leaf has 2 zeros after it, then the next element will be the right element of its parent, if current element is itself not the right element and keep checking this recursively. Got my point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like this may work for you. You just need to re build the tree in a pre-order interpretation of the input sequence. The following code doesn't validate the input sequence to check that is a valid tree representation.

```
struct BTNode {
    int data;
    BTNode* left;
    BTNode* right;
}

BTNode* BuildTree(int* sequence, int& pos) {
    int value = sequence[pos++];
    if (value == 0)
        return nullptr;
    BTNode* node = new BTNode;
    node->data = value;
    node->left = BuildTree(sequence, pos);
    node->right = BuildTree(sequence, pos);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: It was soooooo obvious, don't know how I didn't figured it out :( Thank you very much.